# How to check access to document based on related ones?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, permissions, mongoose

I have the following document schemas:

```
var CalendarModel = mongoose.model('Calendar', mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    rooms: [{
        _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        title: {type: String}
    }]
}));

var EventModel = mongoose.model('Event', mongoose.Schema({
    room: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    startTime: {
        type: Date
    },
    endTime: {
        type: Date
    }
}));
```

Each event related to specific room by their id. I have the following cases:

- User could create/update/delete/edit event
- User could edit room (only title at now)

When user issues query to perform on of the cases I need to check access to perform operation.

Let's say user can delete some event by `_id` and he could if he is owner of calendar where event relates to specific room.

What is the best practice to check writes when user tries to delete event?

**EDIT**: basically I'm looking for best practices for storing permissions for each user's calendar and make fast checking for access. I know that I may query mongo every time that user makes operation (read/edit and etc) but it's overhead. So I need better solution to store application state

Comment: Hi Erik, could you clarify your question? Are you asking how to write a mongo query that would fetch the author for a given Event? Or are you asking about where in your code you should be making this authorization check? (Please make any edits to the original question inline, don't append your clarifications as a comments)